# add flex direction row into table tr row doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I add `flex` to `table > tr`.

Then, I set `flex-direction` to `row`.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  background-color: #ddd
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  background-color: #ddd
}
td:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: #eee
}
td:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But in output, I couldn't see `table> tr > td` in `100%` `tr` `row` like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|     1     |          2          |  3  |  4  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/tu9owcdz/)

Comment: try `colspan="2"`

Comment: disable td padding like  : td { padding : 0 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set td padding to 0

```
td {
  padding:0;
}
```